# Driver do Firebird

Tags: java, firebird, axis2

Estou tentando criar uma webservice com firebird. Fiz os códigos com base em uma videoaula de MySQL e fui tentando alterar para funcionar no firebird. Mas obviamente não deu certo. Vamos aos códigos:

Classe `ConectaFirebird`:

```
package br.com.realsysten.SigadmWS;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConectaFirebird {

private static final String URL = "jdbc:firebird://localhost/SIGADM.FDB";
private static final String USER = "SYSDBA";
private static final String SENHA = "masterkey";

public static Connection obtemConexao() throws SQLException{

    try {
        Class.forName("com.firebird.jdbc.Driver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, SENHA);
}

}
```

Ele cai no `ClassNotFoundException`.

no console aparece isto:

> [INFO] Clustering has been disabled
>       [WARN] Unable to instantiate deployer org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer; see debug logs for more details
>       mai 20, 2016 12:01:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>       GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.(RepositoryListener.java:61)
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
>           at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
>           ... 30 more
>
> mai 20, 2016 12:01:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>       GRAVE: Allocate exception for servlet AxisServlet
>       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.(RepositoryListener.java:61)
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
>           at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
>           at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu tinha baixado esta pasta deste link naquele dia que fiz esta pergunta, devo adicionar todos os JAR dentro da pasta lib?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou tenho que baixar outra coisa neste site do axis2?
quando inicio o tomcat e abro o localhost aparece isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando clico em services ocorre o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deu certo, baixar o JAR org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlschema-1.4.3_1

porem quando clico em services aparece isto agora:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e se clico no primeiro link aparece isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> [ERROR] The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR)
>   /SigadmWS/services org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be
>   found for the endpoint reference (EPR) /SigadmWS/services     at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPhase.java:79)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:324)     at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:250)    at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:156)   at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:242)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:869)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:290)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

é outro jar?

não sei onde fica o endpoits mas as classes que tenho aqui são:

ConectaFireBird:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConectaFirebird {

private static final String URL = "jdbc:firebird://localhost/SIGADM.FDB";
private static final String User= "SYSDBA";
private static final String Senha = "masterkey";

public static Connection obtemConexao() throws SQLException{
    try {
        Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, User, Senha);
}

}
```

classe Mesa:

```
import java.sql.Date;

public class Mesa {

private int id;
private String barras;
private String tipo;
private Date data;
private int lugares;
private String situacao;
private String descricao;
private double credito;

public Mesa(){

}

public Mesa(int id, String barras, String tipo, Date data, int lugares, String situacao, String descricao,
        double credito) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.barras = barras;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.data = data;
    this.lugares = lugares;
    this.situacao = situacao;
    this.descricao = descricao;
    this.credito = credito;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getBarras() {
    return barras;
}

public void setBarras(String barras) {
    this.barras = barras;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

public Date getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Date data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public int getLugares() {
    return lugares;
}

public void setLugares(int lugares) {
    this.lugares = lugares;
}

public String getSituacao() {
    return situacao;
}

public void setSituacao(String situacao) {
    this.situacao = situacao;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public double getCredito() {
    return credito;
}

public void setCredito(double credito) {
    this.credito = credito;
}



}
```

Classe MesaDAO:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MesaDAO {

    public ArrayList<Mesa> buscarTodos(){
        ArrayList<Mesa> lista = new ArrayList<Mesa>();

        try {
            Connection conn = ConectaFirebird.obtemConexao();
            String querry = "SELECT * FROM CONTROLE";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(querry);
            ResultSet rSet = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rSet.next()){
                Mesa mesa = new Mesa();

                mesa.setId(rSet.getInt(1));
                mesa.setBarras(rSet.getString(2));
                mesa.setTipo(rSet.getString(3));
                mesa.setData(rSet.getDate(4));
                mesa.setLugares(rSet.getInt(5));
                mesa.setSituacao(rSet.getString(6));
                mesa.setDescricao(rSet.getString(7));
                mesa.setCredito(rSet.getDouble(8));

                lista.add(mesa);
            }

            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return lista;



    }



}
```

Comment: Você pode achar o jar que esta faltando aqui http://www.findjar.com/class/org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver.html

Comment: baixo todos os jar?

Comment: os links para download estão quebrados

Comment: Não você vai baixar apenas o que fizer sentido para o seu projeto, que provavelmente deve ser org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlschema-1.4.3_1.jar. 
Use esse site findjar apenas para localizar os jars necessários para o seu projeto, depois pode jogar no google mesmo para baixar ele.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlschema/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlschema-1.4.2_1.jar.zip

Comment: deu certo baixando este org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlschema-1.4.3_1.jar, porem ocorreu outro problema, editei o post novamente com o novo erro.

Comment: achei isto, mas é a mesma coisa http://findjar.com/class/org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchemaForm.html

Comment: Agora ele está conseguindo ler o schema porém você está com problemas de configuração dos seus endpoints do seu webservice. Alias as URLs estão estranhas mesmo.

Coloque aqui a confguração do seu service e dos seus endpoints.

Comment: acho que eu não mexi nisto, sou novato nessa parte de webservice, pode me dizer onde acho esses endpoints e as config do service?

Comment: Editei o post com todas as classes do meu projeto, não sei se é isto que você queria

Comment: Da uma lida neste how-to aqui https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-apacheaxis/ você primeiro tem que entender o que é um webservice, endpoints e como configura-los. Depois se preocupe com qual banco vai se conectar.

Comment: esse wsdl file é um arquivo padrão? ou deve ser criado? estou meio que boiando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu stacktrace há isto:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver`

Ou seja, o seu problema não está no firebird, e sim no JARs do Axis 2 que parecem estar faltando. Você pode obtê-los aqui: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.html

Comment: dei uma editada no post ._.

Answer (score 1):

Baixe o driver do Firebird (http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/) e coloque o JAR correspondente no seu classpath na hora de executar a aplicação.

E também, ao invés de `"com.firebird.jdbc.Driver"`, use `"org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver"`.

Comment: com relação ao jar já havia baixado e instalado corretamente mas não sabia o caminho do driver a colocar, mas continua não funcionando